# How to do Pagination for JSON data in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, json, pagination

I don't have direct access to database from PHP. if it was so, I could have done pagination simply. Here I send a GET request to a PHP web service, and the result from the database is fetched as JSON. And I have a table and I want to show the database values into it. Since database table contains more than 1000 records, I want to show the data paginated.

```
$json_data_fromdb= httpGet($ur3l."fromtable?u=".$var1."&ip=".$var2);
$array = json_decode($json_data_fromdb, true);
$x=count($array['qqq']);
$array = $array['qqq'];
```

The above given is the GET request and the corresponding JSON is stored in $array.

How can I do pagination to a JSON array  using PHP??

My JSON data is like this:

```
{
    "qqq": [
        {
            "a": "Conne",
            "b": "1",
            "c": "2014-05-19T15:40:06+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "dani",

                "d6": "admin"
            }

        },
        {
            "a": "igroup'",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",

                "d6": "eev"
            }

        }
    ]
}
```

And below given is my HTML table

```
 <table id="show" >
        <thead >
        <tr >
            <th>1stheader</th>
            <th>2stheader</th>
            <th>3stheader</th>
            <th>4stheader</th>
            <th>5stheader</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++)
        {
            $a= $array[$i]['a'];
            $b= $array[$i]['d']['d1'] ;
            $c= $array[$i]['d']['d2'] ;
            $d= $array[$i]['b'];
            $e= $array[$i]['c'];

            ?>
            <tr >
                <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $b  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo c;   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo d;   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $e;  ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }  ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Handling JSON arrays are one issue. Pagination is another issue. They are not necessarily tied together. You should ask 2 separate questions depending on where problems come from.

Comment: Pagination is the issue. I have printed all the data in JSON to an html table using a simple for loop. But how can I do pagination there? That's my question. @Mihai Stancu

Comment: could you show us the structure of array['qqq'] or your html table?

Comment: you could convert them into an array, then chunk the values according to how many rows you want per batch, then the batches become the pages, the paging links are another matter.

Comment: Since you already have all the data of the JSON available (in a variable) how is this different from implementing pagination directly from the DB?

Comment: I have added the JSON format @ Mohammad Alabed

Comment: Does the data change, or is it mostly static?

Comment: No data is dynamic. I have added the HTML code. @serakfalcon

Comment: You can have a look at the HTML code also. @Mohammad Alabed

Comment: @TheJoker I see your code and html so, could you try my answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to really just do it in PHP you can just roll up your own. But I strongly suggest using jquery plugins to do the pagination to make it easier. That being said, if you want to roll up your own you could do something like this (lil bit messy but something like this.) Consider this example:

```
$sample_data = '{ "qqq": [ { "a": "Conne", "b": "1", "c": "2014-05-19T15:40:06+05:30", "d": { "d1": "dani", "d6": "admin" } }, { "a": "test1", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-    05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test2", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test3", "b":     "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test4", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a":     "test5", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test6", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev"     } }, { "a": "test7", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test8", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev",     "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test9", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test10", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": {     "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } }, { "a": "test11", "b": "1235", "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30", "d": { "d1": "sev", "d6": "eev" } } ]}';

// just normal getting data
$raw_data = json_decode($sample_data, true);
$raw_data = $raw_data['qqq'];

// use get variable to paging number
$page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$limit = 5; // five rows per page
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit; // offset
$total_items = count($raw_data); // total items
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit);
$final = array_splice($raw_data, $offset, $limit); // splice them according to offset and limit

?>
<!-- print links -->
<?php for($x = 1; $x <= $total_pages; $x++): ?>
    <a href='index.php?page=<?php echo $x; ?>'><?php echo $x; ?></a>
<?php endfor; ?>
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
    <tr><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th><th>Time</th><th>Column 4</th></tr>
    <?php foreach($final as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach($value as $index => $element): ?>
            <td><?php echo !is_array($element) ? $element : implode(',', $element); ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

[**Just a sample**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/TyLOWV)

Answer (score 3):

This is a working code based on your example

```
<?php
$json = '{
    "qqq": [
        {
            "a": "Conne",
            "b": "1",
            "c": "2014-05-19T15:40:06+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "dani",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "inmin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "1",
                "d4": "web",
                "d5": "8e11e4f63",
                "d6": "admin"
            },
            "e": "145"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup2",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup3",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup4",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup5",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup6",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup7",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup8",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        },
        {
            "a": "igroup9",
            "b": "1235",
            "c": "2014-05-27T11:23:11+05:30",
            "d": {
                "d1": "sev",
                "d2": {
                    "d2a": "1",
                    "d2b": "admin",
                    "d2c": "1",
                    "d2d": "1",
                    "d2e": "1",
                    "d2f": "1"

                },
                "d3": "7",
                "d4": "c",
                "d5": "changed",
                "d6": "eev"
            },
            "e": "132"
        }
    ]
}';
echo '<pre>';
$jsonarray = json_decode($json,true);
$page = !isset($_GET['page']) ? 1 : $_GET['page'];
$limit = 5; 
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
$total_items = count($jsonarray['qqq']); 
$total_pages = ceil($total_items / $limit);
$array = array_splice($jsonarray['qqq'], $offset, $limit);

for($j=1;$j<=$total_pages;$j++) {
    echo "<span><a href='test.php?page=$j'>$j</a></span>";
}
?>

<table id="show" >
        <thead >
        <tr >
            <th>1stheader</th>
            <th>2stheader</th>
            <th>3stheader</th>
            <th>4stheader</th>
            <th>5stheader</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        for($i=0; $i<5; $i++)
        {
            $a= $array[$i]['a'];
            $b= $array[$i]['d']['d1'] ;
            $c= $array[$i]['d']['d2']['d2a'] ;
            $d= $array[$i]['b'];
            $e= $array[$i]['c'];

            ?>
            <tr >
                <td><?php echo $a; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $b  ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $c;   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $d;   ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $e;  ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php }  ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Please rename the file test.php with your file name

Answer (score 0):

I well give you small example and hope help you:

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //init pagenation
             var page =  $("#page option:selected").val();
             $.each($("tr"), function(key, value) {
                    if($(this).attr("id") != page){
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                    }else{
                        $(this).css("display", "block");
                    }
                });

        //do pagenation          
            $("#page").change(function(){
                 var page =  $("#page option:selected").val();
                 $.each($("tr"), function(key, value) {
                        if($(this).attr("id") != page){
                            $(this).css("display", "none");
                        }else{
                            $(this).css("display", "block");
                        }
                    }); 
            });
         });                
</script>
```

html+php:

```
<?php
    $myArr = array('employee-1', 'employee-2', 'employee-3', 'employee-4', 'employee-5');
    $perPage = 2;//The number of items per page
    $output = '<table>';
    $counter = 0;
    $option = 1;// page ids
    foreach($myArr as $name){
        $output .= "<tr id='$option'><td>$name</td></tr>";
        $counter++;
        if($counter == $perPage) {$option++; $counter = 0;}
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    $output .= "<select id='page'>";
    for($i=1; $i <= $option; $i++){
        $output .= "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
    echo $output; 
?>
```

but for your code :

jQuery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        //init pagenation
             var page =  $("#page option:selected").val();
             $.each($(".myTr"), function(key, value) {
                var idInLoop = $(this).attr("id");
                    if(idInLoop != page){
                        $(this).css("display", "none");
                    }else{
                        $(this).css("display", "block");
                    }
                });

        //do pagenation          
            $("#page").change(function(){
                 var page =  $("#page option:selected").val();
                 $.each($(".myTr"), function(key, value) {
                    var idInLoop = $(this).attr("id");
                        if(idInLoop != page){
                            $(this).css("display", "none");
                        }else{
                            $(this).css("display", "block");
                        }
                    });
            });
         });                
</script>
```

php+html:

```
<?php
    $output = ' <table id="show" >
                    <thead >
                    <tr id = "header">
                        <th>1stheader</th>
                        <th>2stheader</th>
                        <th>3stheader</th>
                        <th>4stheader</th>
                        <th>5stheader</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>';
    $perPage = 2;//The number of items per page
    $counter = 0;
    $option = 1;// page ids

    for($i=0; $i<$x; $i++){
        $a= $array[$i]['a'];
        $b= $array[$i]['d']['d1'] ;
        $c= $array[$i]['d']['d2'] ;
        $d= $array[$i]['b'];
        $e= $array[$i]['c'];

        $output .= "<tr class='myTr' id='$option' >";
            $output .= "<td>$a</td>";
            $output .= "<td>$b</td>";
            $output .= "<td>$c</td>";
            $output .= "<td>$d</td>";
            $output .= "<td>$e</td>";
        $output .= "</tr>";

        $counter++;
        if($counter == $perPage) {$option++; $counter = 0;}
    }
    $output .= "</tbody></table>";  

    $output .= "<select id='page'>";
    for($i=1; $i <= $option; $i++){
        $output .= "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
    }
    echo $output;    
?>
```

Comment: I tried your answer. It works fine. but the outpuy stays in the page only for a second. Then my page becomes blank. But the pagination stays. even if I click on a page number, nothing comes up. @Mohammad Alabed

Answer (score 0):

You have several options available, the 'best' two I would suggest are the following:

PHP solution:

use sessions, (aka put `session_start();` before every php file that will need access to session variables, also add a script to cause the session to timeout)

Store the DB output to a session variable, if the session variable is not set.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['tabledata'])) {
    $json_data_fromdb= httpGet($ur3l."fromtable?u=".$var1."&ip=".$var2);
    $array = json_decode($json_data_fromdb, true);
    $_SESSION['count']=count($array['qqq']);
    $_SESSION['tabledata'] = $array['qqq'];
}
```

Then, you can simply paginate through the data, by sending a request for a certain range of values.

Alternatively, you can use a javascript solution like [Datatables](https://datatables.net/)
And either load all the information and let datatables filter it, or let datatables communicate with the other PHP server directly.