# How to paginate json response in Laravel Blade

Tags: json, pagination, laravel-blade

[image: JSONresponse]

I have an API that can get by searching keyword(s).

I want to consume it with Laravel Blade and with pagination. So, I made a ViewHadController:

```
    public function cari(Request $request)
    {
        $cari = $request->cari;
        $response = Http::get("http://hadits.test/api/hadall/cari?isi=$cari");
        $data = $response->json();
        //dd($data);
        return view('hadits', compact('data'));
    }
```

And this is my view.blade.php:

```
 <body>
    <div class="container">

            <nav class="navbar navbar-light sticky-top" style="background-color: #e3f2fd;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <form class="d-flex" action="/cari" method="GET">
                @csrf
                <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Cari Hadits..." name="cari" value="{{ old('cari') }}">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            </nav>

  </div>
    
    <div class="container">
    <table class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">No Hadits</th>
      <th scope="col">Kitab</th>
      <th scope="col">Hadits</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @php
        $no=0;
    @endphp
    @if(isset($data))
        @foreach ($data['data'] as $had)
            @php
                $no++;
            @endphp
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{  $no }}</td>
            <td>{{ $had['NoHdt'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $had['Kitab'] }}</td>
            <td>{{ $had['Isi_Arab'] }} <br>
            {{ $had['Isi_Indonesia'] }}   </td>
            </tr>
       @endforeach
    @endif
  </tbody>  
    {{ $data['data']->links }}
</table>
    </div>
    

</body>
```

with this web.routes:
`Route::get('/{cari}', 'ViewHadController@cari');`

In Laravel Docs Pagination, always gave me: `{{ $data['data']->links }}`
But that's non-object: `Trying to get property 'links' of non-object`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best answer so far: i can't! Laravel pagination is for eloquent.

[How to use Guzzle with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52068613/how-to-use-guzzle-with-pagination)