# Pagination on PHP webpage using JSON data

Tags: php, html, json

I am beginner in Php. I have Json data which I get from REST services. I want to paginate JSON data into table by various pages. I retrieve data on first page but remaining data was not shown on that page that's why I want to display pagination on Table. I visit to [How to do Pagination for JSON data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23909250/how-to-do-pagination-for-json-data-in-php) that site but I don't get it fully understand. Below is my json data which I am getting from REST service.

```
[
{
    "bookingid": 75,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201881966",
    "customerName": "",
    "customerMobileNumber": "9850944481",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/19/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "12:12 AM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 76,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201881976",
    "customerName": "",
    "customerMobileNumber": "9850944481",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/19/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "07:05 PM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 77,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201882077",
    "customerName": "",
    "customerMobileNumber": "",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "04:06 PM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 79,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201882079",
    "customerName": "",
    "customerMobileNumber": "",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "07:10 PM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 104,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK2018820104",
    "customerName": "Rakesh Deshmukh",
    "customerMobileNumber": "8745938475",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "04:07 PM",
}
{
    "bookingid": 82,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201882082",
    "customerName": "Muzzameel Sayyad",
    "customerMobileNumber": "",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "11:13 PM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 83,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201882083",
    "customerName": "Muzzameel Sayyad",
    "customerMobileNumber": "",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "11:29 PM",
},
{
    "bookingid": 99,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK201882085",
    "customerName": "Customer One",
    "customerMobileNumber": "8347829296",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "12:34 PM",

},
{
    "bookingid": 103,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK2018820100",
    "customerName": "Customer One",
    "customerMobileNumber": "8347829296",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "8/20/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "11:10 AM",
},
{
    "bookingid": 111,
    "booking_Id": null,
    "bookingNumber": "BK2018821106",
    "customerName": "Customer One",
    "customerMobileNumber": "8347829296",
    "customerId": null,
    "bookingDate": "9/6/2018 12:00:00 AM",
    "collection_time": "09:10 PM",

}....]
```

I am counting a data by using count json,

```
$total_records = count(jsonData); // I got 165 from json 
$no_of_records_per_page = 5; // I get 5 records per page
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $no_of_records_per_page); // I got 33 from that formula
```

What I do next I don't understant. Help me to complete my code.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You've already linked to a working example, what is it that you do not understand regarding pagination?

Answer (score -1):

You need to have an offset to set from which number you want to show posts.
In the first load you set the offset to 0, in page number 2 you set the offset to 5, in page number 3 you set the offset to 10...

For a better answer please edit your question with your PHP code.

Hope it helps!

Comment: "_in page number 3 you set the offset to 3_" You mean 10?

Comment: Yes sorry for that, but you have to do it dinamically.